# How to change the default command scope in OSGi with GoGo Shell and enforce custom scopes for custom commands?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, equinox, gogo-shell

I have an OSGi environment which runs on equinox. For the execution of custom comands I use the gogo shell (org.apache.felix.gogo.command, org.apache.felix.gogo.shell).

By default the command scope is set to equinox so the `help` command does not print anything. If I use `felix:help` it does print all of the available commands.

How do I switch the default command scope to `felix`? Is there a way to give the system a startup script which sets that up?

Additionally, how can I force the user to use the scope I introduce in the component property like shown here:

```
property = {
        "osgi.command.scope=myScope",
        "osgi.command.function=myFunc"
    }
```

=> I want that the user has to write `myScope:myFunc` into the shell. Is that possible anyhow?

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own commands since Gogo has *closures*.

```
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g! 
g! h = { felix:help }
felix:help
g! h
felix:bundlelevel
felix:cd
felix:frameworklevel 
...

g! $h
felix:help
```

You can put a startup script in `./etc/gosh_profile`, where `.` is the current working directory.

The `SCOPE` variable sets up a colon separated path for searching the scopes.

```
g! SCOPE='felix:*'
```

Gogo is way more powerful that almost everybody I know thinks. Gogo can basically call any Java function with shell like syntax. You can see some examples here: https://v2archive.enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/gogo.html

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. What about enforcing the custom scopes of my commands? Do you have any idea about that?